# Android WebView as Chrome v25+

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, speech-recognition, webspeech-api

The short answer is :

Can we use Android Studio widget WebView with all Chrome Browser features?
(i searched for answers on stackoverflow, but they all are old, i hope if something has been changed)

And the long answer :

I got customers who asked me to realise speech recognition app for them, their idea is to make web site with some features including speech-to-text. They are founded in using  [Google Web Speech Api](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html). This service works perfectly on Android official Google Chrome app. Loading it in webView causes "Install Chrome v25+" error. I already made an android app using built in Voice Recognition, but customers requirement is to make site with mobile version and use it Android App in WebView.

So, my 'sub' questions are :

1)If this it is not possible than why?(Android Chrome app can work as full browser, why we cant realise it in our apps)

2)Can some IDEs based on web(React Native, PhoneGap) help me to realise this idea?

3)May be you know other Speech Recognition services that can work similar in Web Page and Android WebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Chromium Project (which feeds into the closed source Google Chrome) issue list:

[Support for Web Speech API in Android WebView](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=487255)

Based on that thread, Web Speech API isn't available in the Android System WebView, but is being investigated.

You may want to try [Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) which is supported on Android 4.3 and up. As the tab actually uses the Chrome app, it may allow access to the APIs you want, but I haven't tried it. Do report back what you find.

Comment: Thanks, yes with Chrome Custom Tabs all works as it required!